# How do i bind a ListViewItem to Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

How do i bind a grid to ListViewItem's content in Listview datatemplate, Like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AListInMyViewModel}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView >
        <GridViewColumn Header="VariableDetails" Width="10">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
               <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DetailPanel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and in my ViewModel i have the AListInMyViewModel that its every item has a property like this:

```
Panel DetailPanel{
  get
    {
       Grid MyGrid=new Grid();

       ...
       return MyGrid;
    }
```

now i want to show the specified grid (DetailPanel) in a cell of the MyListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying that your `Panel` is `public`.  Also, how have you declared your list?  I'm not sure about the way you've set your DataContext in the XAML -- I've never done it that way before.  Just to eliminate that as a potential issue, try setting the DataContext to your viewmodel in code-behind.  Also, remember to look at your output window after you start your application to see where you could have problems with your databinding, and add these messages to your question.